# Converting to hexadecimal

Tags: python, binary, hex

I have this binary string

```
bit_string = "0000111100001111010001111011001110110010010100110000101100001111"
```

I can't understand this code snippet to convert it to hexadecimal

```
res = '{:0>16x}'.format(int(bit_string, 2))
```

Comment: It's not even a question and you have not pointed out what part of the expression you do not understand and what you have researched so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is converting the binary representation of your number into an int, use the `int` method, with base `2`

```
bit_string = "0000111100001111010001111011001110110010010100110000101100001111"

value = int(bit_string, 2)
print(value)  # 1085164872336083727
```

Then regarding the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) `format_spec > type` part

> 'x' : Hex format. Outputs the number in base 16, using lower-case letters for the digits above 9.

So use the following to get hex output

```
res = '{:x}'.format(value)
print(res)  # 0f0f47b3b2530b0f
```

---

Now more formatting with `{:0>16x}`

- `>` : Forces the field to be right-aligned within the available space
- `0` : pad with the value `0` and not space
- `16` : pad at length 16

That doesn't affect your value, which is already of length 16 in hex, but here with smaller values

```
res = '{:0>16x}'.format(10)
print(res)  # 000000000000000a

res = '{:0<16x}'.format(123456)
print(res)  # 1e24000000000000
```